# Can't Figure How to use case_when and grepl to calculate per 100k for different years

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, case, grepl

As part of a project with COVID data, I need to calculate the rates per 100,000 people for my table. The math itself is easy, the hard part is that there is population data for two different years: 2020, and 2021. I have data from 2020 to 2022. I need to calculate the rate for 2020 using the 2020 population estimate, and the rates for 2021 and 2022 using the 2021 estimate. These all have to go in the same columns.

It was suggested to me in the assignment to use mutate(case_when(grepl), but grepl is a logic operator and I have no clue where to start. The question and expected answers are shown below:

Edit: code I've tried plus given error:

[image: error code]

[image: question]

[image: desired results]

Any tips on how to use case_when and grepl, or how to build my own function, would be greatly appreciated.

So far, I have tried

```
us_totals %>%
  mutate(total_deaths = case_when(
                          grepl("2020", date) ~ (deaths / estimated_population_2020) * 100000),
                          TRUE ~ (deaths / estimated_population_2021) * 100000)
```

I know that's not correct, and I know that grepl and case_when don't take that format, but I'm at a loss.

I've also tried creating my own function to do these calculations, but nothing has worked so far.

For expected results, see above.

Comment: If `estimated_population_2020` and `estimated_population_2021` are defined in your environment, I would expect this to work. What result / error are you getting? btw, is `deaths` a column or do you mean `total_deaths`?

Comment: @Jon Spring, I'm getting the following error: Error in mutate(., total_deaths = case_when(grepl("2020", date) ~ (deaths/est_pop_2020) * :

Caused by error:
! `TRUE ~ (deaths/est_pop_2021) * 1e+05` must be a vector, not a <formula> object. And deaths is the column for the base value, in order to differentiate between them while I figure out the problem, the per 100k column is notated as total_deaths. For detail, est_pop_2020 and est_pop_2021 are the sum of the population column for each year on a separate dataframe, the fips population data. They are defined and work on their own.

Comment: I think you have a misplaced `)` after the first `100000`, so `TRUE ~ (deaths / estimated_population_2021) * 100000)` is being evaluated as a second, separate `mutate` term. (With unexpected syntax for that.) Remove that and put `))` at the end to close both the `case_when` and the `mutate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fake data:

```
estimated_population_2020 <- 3.0E8 # 300,000,000
estimated_population_2021 <- 3.1E8 # 300,000,000
us_totals <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2021-01-01")),
                        deaths = c(5E5, 6E5))
```

---

Code that works

```
us_totals %>%
  mutate(total_deaths = case_when(
    grepl("2020", date) ~ (deaths / estimated_population_2020) * 100000,
    TRUE ~ (deaths / estimated_population_2021) * 100000))

        date deaths total_deaths
1 2020-01-01  5e+05     166.6667
2 2021-01-01  6e+05     193.5484
```

---

Code from question that fails with the same error. If fails because  the extra `)` at the end of the `grepl` line ends the case_when, so that `TRUE ~ (deaths / estimated_population_2021) * 100000)` is erroneously evaluated as if it's a second variable to define after `total_deaths`, instead of as a second case for the `case_when`. With that removed, you need another `)` at the end, so the `))` conclude both the `case_when` and the `mutate`.

```
us_totals %>%
  mutate(total_deaths = case_when(
    grepl("2020", date) ~ (deaths / estimated_population_2020) * 100000), # EXTRA )
    TRUE ~ (deaths / estimated_population_2021) * 100000) # MISSING )

Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `TRUE ~ (deaths/estimated_population_2021) * 1e+05`.
Caused by error:
! `TRUE ~ (deaths/estimated_population_2021) * 1e+05` must be a vector, not a <formula> object.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```